# Android Same code gives two different outputs (dateFormat)

Tags: android, date-format

Ok, I have a problem I can't manage to solve. I'm developing an app with a friend.

The problem is that with this code the app runs for me, but when my friend runs it, he gets an error (`IllegalArgumentException`) like he still has some tag characters.

```
idical = Html.toHtml(icalarr.get(info.position));
int l = idical.length() - 5;
idical = idical.substring(3, l);
```

So he changed the code to:

```
idical = idical.substring(11, l);
```

now I get the error like I "cut" too many characters. It doesn't make sense, as the code is the same, and we're using identical IDEs and devices

Comment: Can you please show us the value of `idical` on your device and your friend's device?

Comment: What I mean is that the error must be because `idical` has a different value in your 2 apps. Can you output the value of `idical` from both apps and compare them?

Comment: yes sorry,  i comment by phone and it dont send it correctly. the two value are <p>1010 </p> and <p dir=ltr>1010 </p>

Comment: i get the error also if i run the apk compiled by my friend

Comment: Your issue appears to be related to [layoutDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection) - perhaps you each have a local version of some style or regional file. If you take a full directory copy of the entire project from your friend's machine and build it on your machine, do you still get the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated whether you have a different character set encoding than your friend?  In Eclipse this can be found by right-clicking on the project and choosing Properties.  On the page that opens (the Resource page) there are options for encoding and file line delimiters.  If you do not have the same ones, then each system would interpret the file differently, even though the text you see appears the same.

Another option would be to load the raw text into a program like Notepad++ and check the character sets.  You could also look for "invisible" characters there that might be causing an issue.

Comment: i try to set the same character set encoding and also to run the apk cpmpiled by my friend. the error still appear

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're extracting the year from the calendar (which returns `int`) then converting to html, then extracting the numeric part of the result from the html.

While there's clearly some difference in your builds, it seems that it'd be easier for you if you just don't convert the calendar content to html at all, i.e.:

```
idical = icalarr.get(info.position).toString();
```